# Basic ActiveRecord query seems really slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a basic show action and a data set with less than 500 objects.

```
def show
  @report = Report.find(params[:id])
  @keywords = @report.keywords.order("total_value DESC")
end
```

I haven't done any performance testing or optimization yet, but I can't understand why my show action is so slow with such a small data set.

BTW, I'm using the app locally.

**Edit:** development.log

```
Started GET "/reports/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:33 -0400
Processing by ReportsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  [1m[36mReport Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE "reports"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "2"]]
  [1m[35mKeyword Load (1.3ms)[0m  SELECT "keywords".* FROM "keywords" WHERE "keywords"."report_id" = 2 ORDER BY total_value DESC
  Rendered reports/show.html.erb within layouts/application (19552.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19777ms (Views: 19773.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (39ms)


Started GET "/assets/pages.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /pages.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /scaffolds.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/styles.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /styles.css - 304 Not Modified (2ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap-transition.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap-affix.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap-alert.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap-button.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap-carousel.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap-collapse.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap-dropdown.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap-modal.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap-scrollspy.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap-tab.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap-tooltip.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap-popover.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap-typeahead.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /bootstrap.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/keywords.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /keywords.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/pages.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /pages.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/reports.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /reports.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:52 -0400
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)


Started GET "/assets/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-16 11:26:53 -0400
Served asset /logo.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
```

View

```
<table class ="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Keyword</th>
    <th>Avg position</th>
    <th>Total revenue</th>
  </tr>

  <% @keywords.each do |keyword| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= keyword.description %></td>
        <td><%= keyword.avg_position %></td>
        <td><%= keyword.total_value %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd recommend starting with your log files. Not surprised N+1 queries as a result of your view code will be to blame.

Comment: can you provide your `log/development.log` file?

Comment: Both of these queries look fine to me(1.3 or 0.2 ms). look at your other logs db logs or webserver logs and you can do top command to see what's taking your resources. If we helpfull you can up-vote!

Comment: It looks like `Views: 19773.0ms` is taking the longest time to load. I wonder why?

Comment: That must be huge amount of data if the number of records (as you said) are around 500. Am I right?

Comment: No, it's literally simple string and integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Report.find(params[:id])
```

The above query uses the primvary key of your database/model.
That should normally be the quickest query and if its slow, first check is look at your model to see if you have "ID"/primary key field.
2nd, i would check "tail -n 100 log/production.log or development.log

Also, comment out the following statement and see if its cuasing it, then study how to construct the query.

```
@keywords = @report.keywords.all(:order => "total_value DESC", :limit => 5)
```

Comment: Actually, in this case the model is more important to post.

Comment: I do have a has_many and belongs_to association made with a `report_id` for keywords.

Comment: The query doesn't seem to be the problem. It's the view rendering. The view has basic `@keywords` partial. Is this a common problem?

Comment: can you paste the view content

Comment: That's it: Its the each loop. Essentially, in your controller, you're telling it to find a report by ID. Then you telling it to find reports keyword and reach report can have many keywords. I think you need to re-think what exactly you want business rule to be then limit your query. Do you need to display all? if not see my updated answer